# Best choice for passing float arrays in Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

Say there is a C++ class in which we would like to define a function to be called in python. On the python side the goal is being able to call this function with:

**Input**:  of type 2D numpy-array(float32), or list of lists, or other suggestions

**Output**: of type 2D numpy-array(float32), or list of lists, or other suggestions

and if it helps latency/simplicity 1D array is also ok.

One would for example define a function in the header with:

```
bool func(const std::string& name);
```

which has string type as input and bool as output.

What can be a good choice with the above requirements to write in the header?

And finally, after the header file, what should be written in the pyx/pyd file for Cython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cython Input

The most natural Cython type to use for the input interface between Python and Cython would be a 2D [typed memoryview](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html). This will take a 2D numpy array, as well as any other 2D array type that exports the buffer interface (there aren't too many other types since Numpy is pretty ubiquitous, but some image-handling libraries have some alternatives).

I'd avoid using list-of-lists as an interface - the length of the second dimension is poorly defined. However, Numpy arrays are easily created from list-of-lists.

### Cython Output

For output you return either a Cython memoryview, or a Numpy array (easily created from a memoryview with `np.asarray(memview)`). I'd probably return a Numpy array, but make a decision based on whether you want to make Numpy a hard dependency.

### C++ interface

This is very difficult to answer without knowing about your code. If you have existing code you should just use the type that's most natural to that if at all possible.

You can get a pointer from your memoryview with `&memview[0,0]`, and access its attributes `.shape` and `.strides` to get information about how the data is stored. (If you make the memoryview contiguous then you know strides from shape so it's simpler). You then need to decided whether to copy the data, or just use a pointer to the Python-owned data (if C++ only keeps the data for the duration of the function call then using a pointer is good).

Similar considerations apply to the output data, but it's hard to know without knowing what you're trying to do in C++.

Comment: @DavidD Thank you very much for your answer. what I am trying to do on the python side is first giving an array as input to the function call, then the c++ code copies the values in that array into another placeholder and updates a data type which would then be copied to the array that is supposed to be returned to the python side for this function call. It is basically a feedback loop of a robot simulation where the input of the function call is the current positions and the output is control commands.

Comment: The main problem is my basic understanding of C++, I'm still trying to make a very simple working example with the header, pyx, and pyd file over which I can then easily develop the small remaining parts.

Comment: What I don't quite follow right now is "why are you using C++?" Knowing what bits _can't_ be in Python or Cython would make this a lot easier to answer.

Comment: so the reason for C++ is that I have to use a package called ros_control and it is only available in c++, which is actually meant to interface a hardware, but I am interfacing it with a python simulator. Here is a simple example that shows its header file: https://github.com/bandasaikrishna/ros_control_example/blob/master/ros_control_example/include/ros_control_example/robot_hardware_interface.h

Comment: In my case the "double joint_position_;", "double joint_velocity_;" and "double joint_effort_;" are meant as input, and the script updates "double joint_effort_command_;". I didn't understand what you mean by bits. are bits our declarations in the header?

Comment: all I need is passing the arrays accross python to this script, trigger update, and return an array to the python side. I think a simple example that would let me print the passed array in c++ would be a good start for me.

Comment: bits = parts/components/libraries (it was meant it a pretty general sense). Knowing that you need to use that external library is the information I was looking for. I don't think I know enough about that library to really be helpful and I'm struggling to find good documentation though

Comment: well I actually also struggled earlier about it. their documentation is here: http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control but I can also explain what happens. The cpp file that imports the above header example, has a read, update, and write function: https://github.com/bandasaikrishna/ros_control_example/blob/master/ros_control_example/src/robot_hardware_interface_node.cpp , the read function updates the joint_position_ and joint_velocity_ place holders which will be used by the update function to update joint_effort_command_ place holders.

Comment: the write function then sends joint_effort_command_ to the real hardware for applying it. What I plan to do is invoking a call from python side which will send the current robot state from python to be copied in the read function, and automaticaly after doing the update, return the values that are updated now in joint_effort_command_, which I do so far with some ros specific features that are fragile, and is limited by GIL. the GIL problem is not a big issue though.

Comment: a more elaborate documentation http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20hardware%20interface

Comment: I would be glad if you may still had any suggestion for definitions I should use in the header and pyx/pyd file:)