# Cython fastest way to pass a float numbers for high frequency control loops

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cython, memoryview

I have a function(func) in a c++ class and want to call it from the python side to invoke the following sequence with the **lowest latency possible**:

1_on the python side: func(np.array([1,2,3,4,5]) or func([1,2,3,4,5]) or 2D array and any other suggestion you may have for lower latency.

2_on the c++ side: I have a place holder of type [franka::RobotState  robot_state_](https://frankaemika.github.io/libfranka/structfranka_1_1RobotState.html) and I want to copy a part of the above array inside it. something that I may do for example like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        robot_state_.q     [i] = array_that_came_from_python_side  [i];
        robot_state_.dq    [i] = array_that_came_from_python_side  [i+7];
        robot_state_.tau_J [i] = array_that_came_from_python_side  [i+14];
    }
```

3_Then next lines which I have already written will update another place holder of type [franka::Torques _eff_cmd](https://frankaemika.github.io/libfranka/classfranka_1_1Torques.html) which I want to return to the python side and imagine to do it like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
    array_to_return[i] = _eff_cmd[i]
    }
    return array_to_return // to be sent to the python side
```

where the array_to_return can be returned on the python side with any type such as numpy array or list or any other suggestion like the input. and then I will repeat this sequence on the python side with a high frequency since it is basically about a control feedback loop.

my question is how to do this in the fastest way with Cython, what do I define the func with on the c++ side. Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62387234/best-choice-for-passing-float-arrays-in-cython) one possible way that provides a lower latency seems [Memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html), but I couldn't understand it well so far to know what I had better write in the c++ code and in the Cython pyx file. I would appreciate if anyone could guide me about it, and if you also had a suggestions other than memoryviews for **lower latency**.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to performance optimizations you have to measure!

First make sure, that you exactly know, where your hotspot is. You can use `perf` or Intels `vTune` to make sure you optimize the right location.

Than you can write a `google benchmark` test for that specific hotspot.

If the snippet is your hotspot, splitting the loop will help you, since you have contiguous memory access.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        robot_state_.q    [i] = array_that_came_from_python_side  [i+7];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        robot_state_.dq     [i] = array_that_came_from_python_side  [i+7];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        robot_state_.tau_J [i] = array_that_came_from_python_side  [i+14];
}
```

Or it might not do anything because the compilers are very smart these days.

Perhaps `std::memcopy` will do a goo job

```
std::memcpy(robot_state_.q, &array_that_came_from_python_side[0], 7);
std::memcpy(robot_state_.dq, &array_that_came_from_python_side[7], 7);
std::memcpy(robot_state_.tau_J , &array_that_came_from_python_side[14], 7);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. My main problem at the moment more about what to even start with in terms of for example applying the concept of memoryview. How should I define the c++ function and its Cython mirror in the first place.

Comment: my main problem is that I have no clue what to write in the pyx file for such function.